# Not able to change only question title?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, suggested-edits

I show a question that contains duplicate words in it's title. So I tried to remove it by editing the question Bu when i submit edit it says *"Edit can't be submitted. Nothing has changed in it."*

*Why so? Can we edit only question body? or Is it compulsory to change in question to make an edit.?*

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the question you tried to edit?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978294/how-do-i-kill-a-long-running-servlet-process-from-another-servlet) was the question but now the question owner changed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978294/how-do-i-kill-a-long-running-servlet-process-from-another-servlet) shows no edit history, meaning that the asker edited the title within five minutes of asking.

What probably occurred was you loaded the edit page when the title was incorrect, the asker fixed the title, and your edit matched the corrected title.

Comment: now I also think this can be the case.